# How to capture whether user touchor not a particular view in ios

Tags: uiview, ios7.1

Hi I have a `UIView` I want to capture the touch event of that view. If user touch that view I want to pop to one of previous viewcontrollers. Its not a button. Its a view. How can I do that. Please help me. (Its a custom view that extended from UIView class)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add touch events in the view class. Define this method within the view class on which you want to detect touch.

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

You can also add UITapGesture for the same work.

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(TapGesture## Heading ##:)];
    [tapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

    [YOUR_VIEW addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [tapGesture release];
```

make sure that you enabled user interaction of your view by

```
[YOUR_VIEW setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```